# XML parsing not storing entire value on random nodes

Tags: android

I have an android app that, via a service, downloads an xml file from a web server, parses the data and updates a database via a content provider. This all works fine.

My problem is that on some of the nodes of the xml file it will not process the entire string it contains. I have a xml structured like...

```
<books>
    <book>
        <author>Test Author</author>
        <title>Example title</title>
        <datestamp>201212251300</datestamp>
    </book>
    about 30 more book nodes...
</books>
```

I use the datestamp value (which is a YYYYMMDDHHMM value) to order the books but occasionally it will only save 4 or 5 characters of the datestamp on 1 or 2 of the books, which then messes up the sorting on the column.

I am probably going to change the datestamp column to a single number to get round it but has anyone seen this before?

Thanks.

Snippet from the DefaultHandler class showing where the value is added to the ContentValues object...

```
@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    if(this.in_datestamp_tag){
        cv.put(DbAdapter.TBL_BOOK_ROW_DATESTAMP, new String(ch, start, length));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide code snippet where you parse datestamp values?

Comment: Why dont you enter time in MilliSeconds..??

Comment: I could.. but it's likely I'll get the same problem.

Comment: @peterpan- But you can store it as Long and the convert to datetime format.!!